# reading schema error: Could not get list of tables rom database. Probably a JDBC driver

Tags: java, eclipse, hibernate, maven, jdbc

So, I've been trying for weeks to find out what the problem is with my hibernate configuration. I admit, I'm fairly new to web development so forgive me for common errors. I'm trying to make a simple login page using a maven web application and hibernate framework with an mysql database. The driver can connect to the database as seen in the source explorer above. But the hibernate connection throws the reading schema error.

And when I try to run the project, I get a unknown entity error for the mapped class. I have looked at similar problems online but the solutions don't seem to be working and their errors are different.

The User class:

```
package ProjectName.users;
import java.util.Date;

public class User {
 private int user_no;
 private String user_name;
 private String password;
 private String full_name;
 private String email_id;
 private String about_me;
 private Date dob;
 private Date doj;

 public String getUser_name() {
  return user_name;
 }
 public void setUser_name(String user_name) {
  this.user_name = user_name;
 }
 public String getPassword() {
  return password;
 }
 public void setPassword(String password) {
  this.password = password;
 }
 public String getFull_name() {
  return full_name;
 }
 public void setFull_name(String full_name) {
  this.email_id = full_name;
 }
 public String getEmail_id() {
  return email_id;
 }
 public void setEmail_id(String email_id) {
  this.email_id = email_id;
 }
 public void setAbout_me(String about_me) {
  this.about_me = about_me;
 }
 public String getAbout_me() {
  return about_me;
 }
 public Date getDob() {
  return dob;
 }
 public void setDob(Date dob) {
  this.dob = dob;
 }
 public Date getDoj() {
  return doj;
 }
 public void setDoj(Date doj) {
  this.doj = doj;
 }
 @Override
 public String toString() {
  return "userdb [user_no=" + user_no + "user_name=" + user_name + ", 
  password = " + password +", full_name = "+full_name+", dob = " + dob + ", doj = " + 
  doj + ", email_id=" + email_id + ", about_me=" + about_me + "]";
 }
}
```

The hibernate configuration file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
    "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN"
    "http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-configuration>
<session-factory>
    <property 
  name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.password">password</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/userdb</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.username">root</property>
    <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLInnoDBDialect</property>
    <property name="show_sql">true</property>
    <property name="format_sql">true</property>
    <property name="hbm2ddl.auto">update </property>
    <mapping resource="User.hbm.xml" />
</session-factory>
```

I've crossed out the name of the project due to personal reasons. Below is the specifics of the project.

[From top: Hibernate Configurations [jboss tools], Java build path, Data Source Explorer, Stack Trace from console, web deployment Assembly](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qmcEf.png)

Stack trace:

```
Sep 09, 2017 1:58:36 PM org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.DdlTransactionIsolatorNonJtaImpl getIsolatedConnection
INFO: HHH10001501: Connection obtained from JdbcConnectionAccess [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator$ConnectionProviderJdbcConnectionAccess@240fdbb5] for (non-JTA) DDL execution was not in auto-commit mode; the Connection 'local transaction' will be committed and the Connection will be set into auto-commit mode.
org.hibernate.UnknownEntityTypeException: Unable to locate persister: projectName.users.User
    at org.hibernate.metamodel.internal.MetamodelImpl.locateEntityPersister(MetamodelImpl.java:637)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.locateEntityPersister(SessionImpl.java:2942)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.access$1800(SessionImpl.java:203)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl$IdentifierLoadAccessImpl.<init>(SessionImpl.java:2693)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl$IdentifierLoadAccessImpl.<init>(SessionImpl.java:2679)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.byId(SessionImpl.java:1200)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.get(SessionImpl.java:1073)
    at ProjectName.users.UserDao.getuserByUID(UserDao.java:108)
    at ProjectName.users.Validation.doPost(Validation.java:69)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:660)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:199)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:475)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:80)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:625)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:342)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:498)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:796)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1372)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Sep 09, 2017 1:58:36 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [Validation] in context with path [/ProjectName] threw exception
javax.persistence.TransactionRequiredException: no transaction is in progress
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.checkTransactionNeeded(SessionImpl.java:3461)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.doFlush(SessionImpl.java:1425)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.flush(SessionImpl.java:1421)
    at ProjectName.users.UserDao.getuserByUID(UserDao.java:112)
    at ProjectName.users.Validation.doPost(Validation.java:69)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:660)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:199)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:475)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:80)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:625)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:342)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:498)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:796)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1372)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Then this is the servlet that retrieves the form from the index page.

```
package ProjectName.users;

import java.io.IOException;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpSession;
public class Validation extends HttpServlet {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

/**
 * @see HttpServlet#HttpServlet()
 */
public Validation() {
    super();
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}

/**
 * @see HttpServlet#doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
 */
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    response.getWriter().append("Served at: ").append(request.getContextPath());
}

/**
 * @see HttpServlet#doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
 */
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    HttpSession session = request.getSession();
    String mode = request.getParameter("mode");
    UserDao u2 = new UserDao();
    String un=request.getParameter("username");
    String pw=request.getParameter("password");

    if(mode.equals("register"))
    {



        String pw2=request.getParameter("password2");
        if(!pw.equals(pw2))
        {   
            String alert = "PM"; //Password Mismatch
            session.setAttribute("alert",alert);
            response.sendRedirect("index.jsp");
        }
        if(u2.getuserByID(un,pw)==null)
        {
            User u1 = new User();
            u1.setUser_name(un);
            u1.setPassword(pw);
            u2.addUser(u1);
            session.setAttribute("username", un ); 
            session.setAttribute("password",pw);
            response.sendRedirect("Profile.jsp");
        }

    }
    else if(mode.equals("login"))
    {
        if(u2.getuserByUID(un)!=null) {
            if(u2.getuserByID(un,pw)==null) {
                String alert = "WP";  //Wrong password
                session.setAttribute("alert",alert);
                response.sendRedirect("index.jsp");
            }
            else 
            {
            session.setAttribute("username", un ); 
            session.setAttribute("password",pw);
            response.sendRedirect("Profile.jsp");
            }
        }
        else
        {
            String alert = "UU";  //Unregistered Username
            session.setAttribute("alert",alert);
            response.sendRedirect("index.jsp");
        }

    }
}

}
```

Comment: Please post the full exception stacktrace and all relevant information in the question itself. Do not use external links or images.

Comment: I have added the stack trace and servlet class but I don't think I can post the hibernate configuration (JBoss Plugin) or Java class path as text and I can't embed images yet.

Comment: Not sure if it is the actual cause, but please compare the `projectName.users.User` in the exception message, and your actual package name `ProjectName.users`; packages are usually case sensitive (may depend on platform), and you really should use lowercase for package names (and preferably reverse domain name for namespacing)

Comment: Ah no, projectname is just a placeholder, I didn't want to put my project's name up since it was a personal project. Sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should add persistence annotations like:

```
@Entity    
@Table
@Id
@Column
```

edit: (like here for example)
http://www.techferry.com/articles/hibernate-jpa-annotations.html

Comment: Isn't it enough to create a hibernate mapping file? (User.hbm.xml)